Spring Boot Entity Relationship Cascade Remove Issue
When delete User record, I want to delete rfid record And when deleting rfid record not want to delete user record , only one rfid allow to use for one user (one to one relationship) also  i don't need to store rfid record id in user record. how to achieve this?
User Entity:
@Entity()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id()
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max=200, min=5, message = "Username must be between 5 and 200 characters")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String passwordHash;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // eml or phn
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthTypes authType;

}

RFID Entity:
@Entity()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "rfid")
public class RFID {

    @Id()
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max=200,min = 10, message = "RFID must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String rfid;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private User user;

    @CreatedDate
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
}

without storing rfid record in the user table I want to delete rfid when deleting user record

I have found a solution:
RFID Entity:
@Entity()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "rfid")
public class RFID {

    @Id()
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max=200,min = 10, message = "RFID must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String rfid;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @CreatedDate
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
}

User Entity:


@Entity()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id()
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max=200, min=5, message = "Username must be between 5 and 200 characters")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String passwordHash;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private  RFID rfid;

    // eml or phn
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthTypes authType;

}

